# Edit datetime in views notifications.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

So I am developing an application on Rails and I want to edit the format of datetime when I call it from the database. I could not find anything online that showed changing it when I have already created the date type in the database.

This is what it currently is showing 2017-11-01 21:36:55 UTC

I want the format to be MM/DD/YYYY 00:00 PM/AM 12 hour clock

```
   create_table "notifications", force: :cascade do |t|
       t.string "title"
       t.datetime "date"
       t.text "content"
       t.datetime "created_at", null: false
       t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    end
```

This code is in my views/notifications/notifications.html.erb

```
<tbody>
    <% @notification.each do |notification| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= notification.title %></td>
        <td><%= notification.first_name %></td>
        <td><%= notification.date %></td>
        <td><%= notification.content %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<td><%= notification.date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p") %></td>
```

**Explanation**

```
%I  - 12 hour format
%p   - AM/PM format
....
```

for more info check doc https://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strftime

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to use the localization system of rails. See [Adding Date/Time Formats](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats). With this you are free to define some date/datetime formats in your locales files, which you can reuse.

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time:
    datetime:
      formats:
        default: "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"
        my_format: "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"
```

Then you apply them with the `l` helper method to your datetime value in the view. Use the default format:

```
<td><%= l(notification.date) %></td>
```

Or use a special format, if it would be differnt:

```
<td><%= l(notification.date, format: :my_format) %></td>
```

Benefit: You may use the defined formats not only in your views. With the `I18n.l` method you can use it in your scripts too and changes to the formats are applied to the whole app. A DRY config in one place.

But at first you need to read about how to [configure](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#configure-the-i18n-module) the internationalization/localization system for your app.